# I am unable to connect successfully to 8266 wifi module using arduino

Tags: arduino, android-wifi, esp8266

Hi I am new to arduino programming and I am have an issue. I have successfully managed to display the wifi using esp8266 module i.e when I run my code the esp8266 module creates a wifi. It also asks for password but after that there is no output of successful connection. I am using the method wifi.softAp(username,password) for creation of wifi network. I have written the following code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "Jeet";//Wifi username
const char* password = "wifibin12"; //Wifi password

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "<h1>hello from esp8266!</h1>");
}

void setup(void) {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

Serial.begin(115200);
//WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
Serial.print("this is my pass");
Serial.print(password);
WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
Serial.print("Setting soft-Ap ... ");
// Wait for connection

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }


//If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP

  server.on("/", handleRoot);      //Which routine to handle at root location

  server.begin();                  //Start server
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
server.handleClient();
}
```

When I run the code I get ............. output continuously on serial monitor. Kindly help me fix this issue if anyone knows what I am doing wrong. Suggestions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's getting stuck to while loop. Wifi.status() returns WL_CONNECTED when it is connected to wifi network (to another Access Point). So if you want just get AP to work you should try this:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "Jeet";            //Wifi username
const char* password = "wifibin12";  //Wifi password

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "<h1>hello from esp8266!</h1>");
}

void setup(void) {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("this is my pass");
  Serial.print(password);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("Setting soft-Ap ... ");
  // Wait for connection

//If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("AP name ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP

  server.on("/", handleRoot);      //Which routine to handle at root location

  server.begin();                  //Start server
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  server.handleClient();
}
```

And WiFi.localIP() doesn't return AP's local ip. Default is 192.168.4.1.

I recommend looking docs and examples from here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/doc/esp8266wifi

Comment: Thank You @Petri. It worked for me. However I am unable to get the serial.print commmands output on my serial monitor i.e on my serial monitor none the above serial.print output is being displayed. Can you just help me on this or give me a suggestion why it is not appearing. I once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you use arduino ide's serial monitor? Do you have correct baud rate (115200)? Also check ground connections.

Comment: Yes I am using arduino ide's serial monitor and I have set baud rate to 115200. Can you let me know what ground connections you are referring to. I am using ESP 8266 01 Module. Can you please let me know what flash size would be usable for getting correct output. I am sending you the link of screenshot of tools configuration. You can view the screenshot from the following link:  
drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw8dCxSUylyKeUlkNjRZZVpXRHc. Kindly let me know if changes reuired. I am very thankful for your help

Comment: If you put some serial print to loop(), can you see them? And you can upload your code without problem?

Comment: Only in loop i am able to get output of serial.print. Is it because of any issue??

Comment: No, setup just goes so fast by. You can keep your serial monitor open while uploading ( if arduino ide is not complaining about permissions ) or put some delay to begin of your setup(), so you have time to open serial monitor before it goes to loop().

Comment: I have another question. I hope you don't mind. Do you know how I can reset the ESP8266 module. I know ESP.reset() is there. but I just wanted to know will it run my code again from start after getting reset. I am very Thankful for your replies.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1722) is explained somehow that ESP.reset() won't always restore correctly from reset(). So you should use ESP.restart() and your code should start from beginning.

Comment: I have added the following code in the loop() block but I am unable to reset the wifi can you please tell me what's wrong in it and suggest me something: void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  server.handleClient(); //my method which I call for getting ouput
  delay(5000);
  ESP.restart(); // I want to restart it after every 5mins
}

Comment: Referring to [FAQ](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/doc/faq) you need to reset ESP once after every serial upload. Resetting can be done by pulling RST-pin to ground. If you are doing multiple uploads, it might be more comfortable to put [reset button (schema)](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?w=300&tok=9b1287&media=esp8266_flash_prog_board_sch.png) to your [board](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?w=300&tok=2c5e2b&media=esp8266_flash_prog_board.jpg)

Comment: I am getting this output on serial port when ESP.restart() is invoked:          ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,7)

wdt reset                                                                                                                                                                                   please let me know what should I do. Again I am very Thankful for your help.

Comment: And it's just looping in restart? First ensure that it gets enough current. USB-serial won't be enought most of the times. And for more error codes, [THIS FAQ](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/faq/a02-my-esp-crashes.md) helps to decrypt them.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I am unable to find the ESP exception decoder in tools bar. I think It may be due to board selection as I am using ESP8266 generic module (ESP8266 01) and they are using ESP8266 12E. I want to restart the ESP8266 after every 5 mins and after every restart it should start executing from the start of the program. Can you tell me after how much time ESP would start functioning once the ESP.restart() is invoked. I also have a query regarding Flash size in tools what Flash size should I use. I am very Thankful for your replies.

Comment: Propably only way for -01 modules to know flash size is to look datasheet of the flash chip on the board ( Chip with fewer legs ). It's propably said almost first in datasheet in bits (8Mbit = 1MB) I have [THESE](https://www.docdroid.net/zHDaT9N/gd25q80bsig-gigadevice.pdf.html). I don't know why restart() or reset() doesn't work always as should but you just need to tweak your code. Delay() function in arduino can also bring problems. You can try something like [THIS](http://pastebin.com/A4rh8CCr)

Comment: Thanks alot Petri. We tried to refer your code but we are still unable to get proper response by using ESP.reset() or by using ESP.restart(). Can you please let us know some alternative or link that you may have used when reset and restart wont be running. I am again very thankful for all your help. Cheers.